# How to clear draw.io sidebars and only access it via a floating menubar?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

So I would like to be able remove the sidebar tools from draw.io and whenever I need them just somehow summon the Format toolbar that floats above the diagram, but can be hidden again. I have seen this done, but I do not know how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click "arrow up/down" as marked you should see Format panel collapses/expands. Then place the cursor on the title "Format" and when "move" cursor appears just drag the panel and drop it wherever you like.

Does this help?
[image]

Comment: not helpful at all. What I am saying is that I do not even know how to get that Format menu to appear. The image I posted above was just an example that I saw online, I cannot make that example happen, I don't know how. So if I click on the fullscreen icon at the top right and then I want to access that Format menu that is just floating there, how do I do so after clicking fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to toggle the *Format* panel.

[image]